# `"\n"` can't run in `new Function()`

Tags: javascript, function

I want to run code dynamiclly, without using `<script>`，so I used `new Function`,but there is a problem when I write `\n` :

```
function run (code) {
    (new Function(code))()
}

run('console.log("run well")') // it work well
run('console.log("\nError")')  // error
```

the result is:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4Esj.png)

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
at new Function (<anonymous>)
at run (<anonymous>:2:3)
at <anonymous>:1:1
```

And we can find the reason in console: the '\n' has been turn to a new line

```
(function() {
  console.log("    // error here
  Error")
})
```

so using **`** to replace **"** can solve this problem:

```
run(`console.log("\nWell")`)

(function() {
  console.log(`    // work here
  Error`)
})
```

but it is not suitable that using **`** in production, so if there other way to let it well done ?

Comment: Use double backslashes to indicate a literal backslash. But don't use `new Function` in the first place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the function body is a string, `\n` will actually be converted to a newline character. You need to escape it by using `\\n`.

```js
function run(code) {
  (new Function(code))()
}

run('console.log("run well")') // it work well
run('console.log("\\nError")') // error
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you forgot to escape the `\n` as `\\n`.

You can re write your code as

```
function run (code) {
    (new Function(code))()
}

run('console.log("run well")')  
run('console.log("\\nError")')
```

Console will be

> run well
>
> Error

Please try this you will get the output.

Note Below is the escaping chars in detail

JavaScript uses the \ (backslash) as an escape character for:[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character)[2]

- \' single quote
- \" double quote
- \ backslash
- \n new line
- \r carriage return
- \t tab
- \b backspace
- \f form feed
- \v vertical tab (Internet Explorer 9 and older treats '\v as 'v instead of a vertical tab ('\x0B). If cross-browser compatibility is a concern, use \x0B instead of \v.)
- \0 null character (U+0000 NULL) (only if the next character is not a decimal digit; else it is an octal escape sequence)
- Note that the \v and \0 escapes are not allowed in JSON strings.

[more details about escape characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you better fix it in the function level than fix all the inputs to the function

You can modify your function to escape any `\n` by `str.replace`

```
function run(code) {
    (new Function(code.replace(/\n/g, "\\n")))()
}
```

This will escape any number of occurrences for the `\n` in `code` by `\\n`.

Hope this helps!